# MS access insert into without duplicate

Tags: ms-access, insert, ms-access-2003

1. MS Access 2003
2. Table main (MobileNo text 255, FirstName text 255, LastName text 255, Address text 255)
3. Table Temp (MobileNo text 255, FirstName text 255, LastName text 255, Address text 255)
4. Main has 100 records
5. Temp has 30 records
6. 10 records are belonging both tables.
7. I like to insert into main from temp those records which does not belongs to main base on MobileNo.

Actually import records from temp without duplicate data in Main.

I write a query following

```
INSERT INTO main (mobileNo, FirstName, LastName, Address) 
VALUES
    (SELECT DISTINCT Temp.[MobileNo], Temp.[FirstName], temp.[LastName], Temp.[Address] 
     FROM Temp 
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM main WHERE Main.[MobileNo] = Temp.[MobileNo]));*
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 forms of the [INSERT INTO Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/insert-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql) in Access SQL.  The one with `VALUES` is used to insert a single row.  Since you want to insert multiple rows, use the version which includes a `SELECT` clause.

Start with a `SELECT` query which returns the `Temp` rows you want to insert.  I think this should be close:

```sql
SELECT
    Temp.MobileNo,
    Temp.FirstName,
    temp.LastName,
    Temp.Address 
FROM
    Temp
    LEFT JOIN main
    ON Temp.MobileNo = main.MobileNo
WHERE main.MobileNo Is Null;
```

Add `DISTINCT` if `Temp` includes duplicate rows.  You may find the unmatched query wizard helpful to create your `SELECT` statement if I didn't get it quite right.

Once you have the correct `SELECT` statement, change it to an `INSERT` query (what the Access user interface calls an "append" query).

```sql
INSERT INTO main
    (
        MobileNo,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        Address
    )
SELECT
    Temp.MobileNo,
    Temp.FirstName,
    temp.LastName,
    Temp.Address 
FROM
    Temp
    LEFT JOIN main
    ON Temp.MobileNo = main.MobileNo
WHERE main.MobileNo Is Null;
```

Comment: Thank HansUp. My problem is solved. Your query is much smart than me.